How does the PersistanceService#streamOf method in CAP for Java loads objects in memory?
I am new to CAP (Cloud Application Programming) with Java. I recently learned that using a ResultSet with Java's JDBC you can load results in memory in batches by streaming them.
When using the PersistanceService#streamOf method, does it also load files in memory in batches or does it load the whole result in memory all at once?
Example Code:
Stream<MyClass> myStream = persistenceService
        .run(Select.from(MyClass_.class).where(data -> data.getId().eq(id)))
        .streamOf(MyClass.class);

I can use a ResultSet directly by using the autowired JdbcTemplate:
jdbcTemplate.queryForStream();

But then I would need to handle the parsing of the ResultSet value to an object of my class myself which I want to avoid if I can.

Hibernate is not intended for working with big sets of objects simultaneously. Everything it loads stays in memory until end of transaction (unless you use evict).  So it is actually doesn't really matter if it use batch or not.

I guess it depends on the underlying jdbc provider, but probably yes, the stream object doesn't call ResultSet.next until you actually interate the stream, so there's a chance it's put in memory by chunks
